# I do not know where my Cmakelists.txt is located

Tags: cmake

Following is my stack trace

```
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
        /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
        /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.22.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake:574 (find_package_handle_standard_args)

src/CMakeLists.txt:63 (find_package)
```

What is the path of the src folder here?

Comment: "What is the path of the src folder here?" - It is the **source directory** of the project, which you passed to `cmake` and where the root `CMakeLists.txt`  is located.

Comment: Im confused as I dont have a src directory or a CMakeLists.txt in my project tree

Comment: A **source directory** is not necessary named `src`. But your project definitely has "root" `CMakeLists.txt`. If you are a beginner in the terminology, then you are better to start from some tutorial. E.g. [here](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/) they describe how to run CMake and introduce "source directory".